# React Native: FlatList keyExtractor & toString() Issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Noob question with React-Native & FlatLists:

What does the 2nd line actually mean ?

```
  data={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i}
```

I borrowed this line of code from a friend (with his permission) and it's kinda gotten me into a warning issue with react-native.

I keep getting a yellow warning telling me that there's a "failed child context type". Which is react-native code for "I'm sorry dear programmer, but I can't find the key field to sort the data you presented me with! Noob! Pfft!". I get that. And the way to solve it is to add .toString() to the field that's denoted as the key Field. The problem is, as you can see, is that's not a key field there but rather > (x,i)=>i.

**So my question is WTH is (x,i)=>i ?**

Barring that, I tried to use what I thought was the id value of the record that I'm pulling: this.state.data.id, as the flatlist sees that datasource as denoted in this.state.data, and it sees it as an array as most you already know. My second question is why can't I use 'this.state.data.id' as the keyfield ?

And if I can't use this.state.data.id as the keyfield, and using the (x,i)=>i thingy (whatever the frak that thing is) and I have to use it, what is it and how would I add .toString() to it ?

Thanks ahead of time.

My apologies for the Noob question.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(x,i)=>i is actually a callback function where x=item and i=index, so you return index as a key. Consider it like:

```
keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index}
```

Since it wants key to be a String, you can use:

```
keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
```

Comment: well that clarifies things. And your solution works. Thank you for the clarity @angelos_lex!

Comment: so I have a question: shouldn't this work as well ? 
keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i.toString()} ? But instead my app throws an error.

Comment: ok, now it's not throwing the error. :-) Well at least one thing is working.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you already know what the `key` prop is for so I won't invest too much time on it. (If in doubt [check the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)).

So let's answer in parts. `(x, i) => i` is an [ES6 lambda function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The `keyExtractor` is a function that receives as the first argument the item from data (in this callback it was called `x`) and the second argument is the element index in data array (in this case called `i`). So the code says "use as key for my element the index in the array".

The `keyExtractor` is necessary because `FlatList` encapsulates the return value of your `renderItem` and needs a `key` for the list. (I can go deeper here if you like).

Note that `keyExtractor` provides keys for each element and not for the list itself, so using `this.state.data.id` would put the same key in all element, which is not what you want.

Finally the `.toString()` part is just because the key type expected by `FlatList` is a string, so the warning.